# What does Amazon mean by my Alexa Skill fails when launching "Modal"?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa skill failed certification for a number of reasons, (including the use of the word "oracle" in the intent which Amazon considers a trademark rather than a word!) but I'm scratching my head over this one:

> 3. The skill consistently returns an error when it is launched "modal".  Please see the following documentation for how to return responses to request sent by Alexa:
>      https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/handling-requests-sent-by-alexa
>
> Additionally, please verify the quality of your voice user interface with the below link for better user experience:
>   https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing
>
> Example:
>
> User: “Alexa start/open/launch i ching oracle”
>
> Skill: “Error: Could not find intent”

The documentation is pretty general and doesn't actually mention anything about launching "Modal."

**My guess** is that if someone invokes my skill without an intent, e.g. "Alexa, talk to MYSKILL" rather than "Alexa, ask MYSKILL about MYINTENT" it returns an error, whereas since it's a one-trick pony it should just respond with content.

The example provided in the documentation for how to respond to a launchrequest instead of an intentrequest is only in Java, however, and I'm a bear of little brain coding in javascript with node.js

Can anyone illuminate if my guess is right about "modal"?

And if I'm right and I need to specify what happens on a launchrequest, what would this Java snippet look like in Javascript?

```
@Override
public SpeechletResponse onLaunch(final LaunchRequest request, final Session session)
throws SpeechletException {

log.info("onLaunch requestId={}, sessionId={}", request.getRequestId(),
session.getSessionId());
return callback(null, MYINTENT);
}
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window). And Java is a trademark (as is the company name) of [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I know what a modal is in javascript and in visual web space. My question refers to how Amazon intends the term in the audio interaction space of Alexa.